# Initializing array in a node of a tree in constructor using VS 2012

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012, constructor, initialization

I am building a general tree in C++. I've simplified my code just to get the idea of what I'm doing. Essentially, I want to store a char array in each of my tree nodes. I know the size of the array and the size and contents of the array will be the same for every node. I was under the impression that VS 2012 was C++11 compliant. When trying to initialize my array this approach doesn't work.

```
class Tree{
public:
    Tree();

private:

struct Node{
    Node* lchild;
    Node* mchild;
    Node* rchild;
    Node* parent;
    std::array<char, 5> arr { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
};

Node* root;

};
```

Neither does this

```
class Tree{
public:
    Tree();

private:

struct Node{
    Node* lchild;
    Node* mchild;
    Node* rchild;
    Node* parent;
    std::array<char, 5> arr;
};

Node* root;

};

Tree::Tree(){
    root = new Node;
    root->parent = nullptr;
    root->lchild = nullptr;
    root->mchild = nullptr;
    root->rchild = nullptr;
    root->arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

}
```

Say I wanted my array to be 30 elements long. Is there a better way to initialize this using VS 2012 than manually doing it in my constructor i.e.

```
root->arr[0] = 'a', root->arr[1] = 'b', root->arr[2] = 'c', root->arr[3] = 'd'.......
```

If there isn't what is a potential workaround for this, or am I stuck doing it 30 times for every node?

Answer (score 0):

intialize `arr` in the Node constructor if you already know the values, e.g.

```
Node::Node():
  arr({/*values...*/}){
        //rest of c.tor body.
}
```

and it's probalby best to null-initialize the rest of `Node` members.

Comment: Am i correct in thinking I should make my `Node` a class instead of a struct? Just to make things easier.

Comment: Out of curiousity, are you coming from a C background?

Comment: @user5447431 The only difference is the default access protection. I would keep it a struct, but add a constructor.

Comment: No. I've never had to put an array into a node structure. Unfortunately, this is an assignment, and I am required to use VS 2012.

Comment: so the only difference between struct and class is that in struct everthing is public by default, and with class everything is private by default. it is best that `Node` will include constructor, destructor , copy constructor and move constructor IMHO.

Comment: So using a `Node` constructor, In my `Tree` constructor when i do `root = new Node;` or declare a new Node in my program anywhere the node comes pre-initialized?

Comment: it calls the compiler generated constructor which does nothing. that t why you need to implement your own

Comment: It appears VS 2012 won't let me initialize the array using a initialization list. All of the pointers will work, but i get syntax errors when trying the array. `Node::Node() : lchild(nullptr), rchild(nullptr), mchild(nullptr), parent(nullptr)` works fine. I guess I am stuck doing it manually, but doing it once in the `Node` constructor is better than for every node.

Comment: upgrade to VS2015, no need to be a masochist